# Create a js object from the output of a for loop

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, object, for-loop

I'm trying to write a js script that takes the contents of a json file and
  applies html encoding (via a node.js package) to the object values and then spits it back out into a json file

I think I have the start and end of what I need to do it. 
 I can see from console.log that the encoding is being applied successfully to each object value but I'm not sure how to coherently recreate a js object from the encoded results of the for loop.

I want to understand how I can recreate the arr variable once the values are encoded (if that is the right way to go about it) so I can then stringify and output a json file.

Thanks

```
var arr = {
  "a": "Some strings of text",
  "b": "to be encoded",
  "c": "& converted back to a json file",
  "d": "once they're encoded"
};
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    var obj = arr[i];
    for(var key in obj){
        var attrName = key;
        var attrValue = obj[key];
        var encodedAttrValue = encode(attrValue);

        console.log(encodedAttrValue); // checking encoding is successful 

       var outputJson = // recreate a js object with the cumulated output of the encoding i.e. each encodedAttrValue 


        var outputFilename = 'encoded.json';
        fs.writeFile(outputFilename, JSON.stringify(outputJson, null, 4), function(err) {
          if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            } else {
            console.log("Encoded version has been saved to " + outputFilename);
          }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `Object.keys(stuffToBeEncoded).map()`.

Comment: Why are you looping over an object as if it were an array, and then looping again inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `Array.prototype.reduce` with `Object.assign` will do

```
// objectMap reusable utility
function objectMap(f,a) {
  return Object.keys(a).reduce(function(b,k) {
    return Object.assign(b, {
      [k]: f(a[k])
    })
  }, {})
}

var arr = {
  "a": "Some strings of text",
  "b": "to be encoded",
  "c": "& converted back to a json file",
  "d": "once they're encoded"
}

var encodedValues = Object.keys(arr).reduce(function(out,k) {
  return Object.assign(out, {[k]: encode(arr[k])})
}, {})

fs.writeFile(outputFilename, JSON.stringify(encodedValues, null, 4), function(err) {
  if (err)
    console.error(err.message)
  else
    console.log("Encoded values have been saved to %s", outputFilename)
})
```

Here's a code snippet with a mocked `encode` function to show you the intermediate `encodedValues`

```js
// pretend encode function
function encode(value) {
  return value.toUpperCase()
}

// objectMap reusable utility
function objectMap(f,a) {
  return Object.keys(a).reduce(function(b,k) {
    return Object.assign(b, {
      [k]: f(a[k])
    })
  }, {})
}

var arr = {
  "a": "Some strings of text",
  "b": "to be encoded",
  "c": "& converted back to a json file",
  "d": "once they're encoded"
}

var encodedValues = objectMap(encode, arr)

console.log(JSON.stringify(encodedValues, null, 4))

// {
//    "a": "SOME STRINGS OF TEXT",
//    "b": "TO BE ENCODED",
//    "c": "& CONVERTED BACK TO A JSON FILE",
//    "d": "ONCE THEY'RE ENCODED"
// }
```

Comment: *`return Object.assign(out, {[k]: encode(arr[k])})`* Is this different from `out[k] = encode(arr[k]); return out;` except that it's one line instead of two? In any case wouldn't it be cleaner to write a little utility called `objectMap`?

Comment: Thanks naomik! Using your snippet worked perfectly when I used it in conjunction with the node.js package. I will take some time to head over to MDN and learn a bit more about those methods as they’re new to me (a js novice) & understand how they work. thankyou

Comment: @torazaburo, i do use an objectMap utility in my own code, but for sake of keeping this code a little less verbose, I skipped it this time. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this in a straightforward way as:

```
newObj = {};
for (k in obj) { newObj[k] = encode(obj[k]); }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `.push(obj)` method when looping through the json object.

First take the `outputJson` out of the loop, then when finishing encoding an object push it to the `outputJson`.

```
outputJson.push({
  attrName: key,
  attrValue: encodedAttrValue
});
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: This will create an array of mini-objects, instead of an object with the values mapped.