# An explanation for this context of the.reduce() method and Object.assign()

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reduce, assign

Based on referencing the method/object definitions on MDN I am trying to construct a layman's step by step explanation of how the following script ([from the previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229656/create-a-js-object-from-the-output-of-a-for-loop)) is working to help my understand of it (and hopefully so I can adapt it further)

There's a few things I don't get so my attempt will probably seem a bit muddled but hoping someone can put me right where I'm off track/confused ...

(n.b. the encode function is just to encode html and required from node.js package)

```
var arr = {
  "a": "Some strings of text",
  "b": "to be encoded",
  "c": "& converted back to a json file",
  "d": "once they're encoded"
}

var encodedValues = Object.keys(arr).reduce(function(out,key) {
  return Object.assign(out, {[key]: endcode(arr[key])})
}, {});

console.log(encodedValues);
```

**Explanation**

Create a variable “encodedValues” which will:

1    `Object.keys(arr)`

loop over and return the object `arr`’s properties in the order they are provided

2    `.reduce(function(out,key)`

First applying the following function to execute on each value in the array ("and reduce it to a single value" *):

3      `return Object.assign(out, {[key]: endcode(arr[key])})`

The function copies the values of all properties from the source object to a target object we will call “out”.

4 The source object has an encoding function `{[key]: encode(arr[key])}` applied to it so that  where `key` is an object `encode` is applied to its property

5    `}, {});`

I assume this part `, {}` is the initialValue for .reduce i.e. the value used as the first argument to the first call of the callback, which starts as an empty object?

6 
`Object.keys` returns an array (of the given object `arr`'s encoded properties in the order they were provided)

7 which is then logged to the console

*I don't understand how or why we ["reduce it to a single value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)" in this case?? 
Doesn't that suggest a concatination of the values is part of the process: 
`"Some strings of text" + "to be encoded" + "& converted back to a json file" + "once they're encoded"`. I don't really get how or why this is part of the working solution

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What `reduce()` does is loop over the array, call your function for each item, and each time, it passes your function the return value of the previous iteration so that you can "build upon" it.

For example, you could use `reduce()` to total up an array of numbers.  The iterator function would take in the running total, add to it, and then return the new total.  Or, you could use it to concatenate a bunch of strings, where the iterator takes in the existing string, concatenates something onto it, and then returns the new string.

In this case, you're simply taking in an object (the parameter named `out`), doing stuff to it, then returning it so that the next iteration can keep working on it.  When `reduce()` gets through all the keys, it will return the object you've been building upon.  That goes into your `encodedValues` variable.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. The contexts I studied for .reduce have been where it returns a single total or concatenates strings so I thought that was intrinsic to the method and on that basis I expected it would return the 'out' object as just a single string of all the concatenated properties fed through it but here (other than the encoding function applied) it seems it just iterates over the specified object and returns it.